# Making a js bookmarklet that opens a website in a new window and makes it fullscreen (mac ver)

Tags: javascript, macos, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, bookmarklet

Basically, I want to make a bookmark, or desktop icon that opens a new window and puts it in a fullscreen desktop (like when you press ctrl+cmd+f on macOS) on Chrome. I already made a bookmarklet that does the first part well (below), but I would like any help on the fullscreen issue. I know the Chrome pseudoscript is limited, but I'm not very experienced with it, so if anyone knows of a method or property I could use, I would appreciate it.

```
javascript:void(open('https://www.notion.so/','targetname','height=5000,width=5000', 'fullscreen:yes','location=no'))
```